# Windows Fonts operating strangely

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-word, fonts

I have a handful of documents on a network share created in a specific font - which is installed on both the machine that created the document and the machine that is reading the document (different machines). However, when they are opened on said machine - they open in the incorrect font, totally different to the font it was created in.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is this through all documents, or just certain types? You've written office as a tag, does this mean, for example, the issue is with Word files? Does Excel have the same issue?

Comment: I have editted the tag - as of now, since it is all I have tested on that remote PC - it is just Word 2010.

Answer (score 2):

Check if any [Font Substitution](http://www.melbpc.org.au/pcupdate/2310/2310article10.htm) is occurring, by going to **File** > **Options** > 
**Advanced**. In the "Show document content" section, click the Font 
Substitution button. The resulting dialog will show which fonts are 
unavailable and which ones are being substituted for them. Then look 
in the C:\Windows\Fonts folder to see whether the "missing" fonts are 
really missing.

If the files are in the Fonts folder, maybe they're corrupted or not 
properly registered. Running the Office installer in Repair Mode 
should fix that.

One way of solving this would be by simply backing up (via right clicking on the values) and deleting all the registry values in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\` Obviously this is an extreme approach that will wipe the preferences, but it appears to do the trick.

If all fails you can try saving the troublesome file in what Word 2010 calls "compatibility mode".